# Why is g++ linked to clang, not clang++, by the mac developer tools?

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang, clang++

I was just trying to explain to someone the difference between compiled and interpreted code, when I was greeted with a

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
```

when calling g++ main.cpp for a simple hello world c++ file.

I looked into this a bit and found ...

```
JM:Desktop user$ which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
JM:Desktop user$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/g++
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  47  4 Dez  2018 /usr/local/bin/g++ -> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
JM:Desktop user$ ls -al /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5  3 Feb 20:29     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -> clang
```

...that g++ is linked to clang and not clang++ and I therefore call the C-compiler.

I just deleted the Developer tools and installed them again - same thing.

Is this normal or did something mess up my system? Does it make any sense? What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple?? Why ask us?

Comment: The wonders of the Apple ecosystem!

Comment: possible cross site dupe: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308830/why-does-g-version-say-llvm-clang

Comment: The issue was that the C compiler was linked instead of the C++ compiler, not gcc vs apple clang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may actually be Homebrew's fault somehow...

```
JM:Desktop user$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

/usr/local/bin is added by Homebrew.

'C++' for example links correctly to clang++ but it is in /usr/bin:

```
JM:Desktop user$ which c++
/usr/bin/c++
```

...and so is /usr/bin/g++.

I solved it by just deleting /user/local/bin/g++. The links are still strange.